# Change size of imageview, sprite, label, etc. depending on screen size iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I've come across this problem when creating `UIImageViews`, on the iPhone 6, it fits nicely, but on the 4s, it is huge!, is there a way to add some logic in the `ViewDidLoad` to change the px size of whatever it is, whether it's a sprite, image, label, etc. ?

Comment: are you using autolayout? storyboard? code only?

Comment: I'm using autolayout and storyboard @HashmatKhalil

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27726886/changing-font-size-in-a-label-for-only-iphone-4s-is-this-possible/27727218#27727218

Comment: ok dont change any rect size cause your using auto layout. click on your uiimageview change view from attribute inspector: scale to fill, scale to fit.... and see which one can fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Just use auto layout and size classes (You access them in IB down and select the sizi class for iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, you could use auto-layout, or you can take a different route. If you chose not to take auto-layout, I would recommend do this, however the down side is that there is a lot of programming.

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; 
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

if (screenHeight == 480) {
    // do iPhone 4s stuff
} else if (screenHeight == 568) {
    // do iPhone 5, 5s, 5c stuff
} else if (screenHeight == 667) {
    // do iPhone 6 stuff
} else if (screenHeight == 736) {
    //do iPhone 6 plus stuff
}
```